# Java UCanAccess problem connecting to a database with password

Tags: java, ucanaccess, jackcess

**very good**

I have been working on a desktop application that connects to an access 2016 database to save some data, everything has gone great, but I need the database to be encrypted to prevent them from freely modifying the data.

I have started to investigate how I can achieve this, I am working with `UCanAccess-5.0.0`, according to what I have read, the connection string changes and now an encryption class is necessary.

I started working with `jackcess-encrypt-4.0.2` but I'm getting some errors and I would like to know if you can help me, I appreciate any help.

I am working with netbeans 12.5 and I am running with java witch ant and jdk 8.

This is my connection class:

```java
package Class;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Conn {

    Connection cn = null;
    Statement st = null;

    public Connection(){
        try {
            String rutafile = "C:\\Users\\Ramej\\Documents\\Projects\\Test\\DB_Q2.accdb;jackcessOpener=Class.CryptCodecOpener";
            String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + rutafile;
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa","123");
            st = cn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection(){
        return cn;
    }

    public void Disconnection(){
        try {
            cn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            System.err.println("Error: "+ e);
        }
    }
}
```

and I have the `CryptCodecOpener` class set up as follows:

```java
package Class;

import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.crypt.CryptCodecProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.JackcessOpenerInterface;

public class CryptCodecOpener implements JackcessOpenerInterface {

    public Database open(File fl, String pwd) throws IOException {
        DatabaseBuilder dbd = new DatabaseBuilder(fl);
        dbd.setAutoSync(false);
        dbd.setCodecProvider(new CryptCodecProvider(pwd));
        dbd.setReadOnly(false);
        return dbd.open();
    }
}
```

When entering the system and connecting to the database I find the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.DEFAULT_BYTE_ORDER from class com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.crypt.impl.BaseCryptCodecHandler
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.crypt.impl.BaseCryptCodecHandler.wrap(BaseCryptCodecHandler.java:349)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.crypt.impl.OfficeCryptCodecHandler.create(OfficeCryptCodecHandler.java:81)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.crypt.CryptCodecProvider.createHandler(CryptCodecProvider.java:130)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.initialize(PageChannel.java:105)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.<init>(DatabaseImpl.java:554)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:415)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:267)
    at Clases.CryptCodecOpener.open(CryptCodecOpener.java:27)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.<init>(DBReference.java:170)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReferenceSingleton.loadReference(DBReferenceSingleton.java:51)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:91)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Clases.Conexion.<init>(Conexion.java:34)
    at Ventana.MenuPrincipal.<init>(MenuPrincipal.java:66)
    at Ventana.MenuPrincipal$11.run(MenuPrincipal.java:511)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I have tried to run with `jackcess-encrypt-4.0.2` and with `jackcess-encrypt-2.1.0` without getting any different result, I have also tried with `bcprov-debug-jdk18on-172`, `bcprov-ext-jdk15on -1.70`, `bcprov-ext-jdk18on-172`. Without finding a solution. I guess I'm not loading any other library or I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, indeed as I suspected my problem was about incompatibility with the libraries, don't take into account that `jackcess-encrypt` and `bcprov` must not only be compatible with each other, but must also be compatible with the version of  `UCanAccess` that you are using, in addition to obviously the version of java.

I had a hard time finding a combination of versions that worked for me for java 1.8, the one I got was:

`ucanaccess-3.0.3.1` , `jackcess-encrypt-2.1.1` , and `bcprov-jdk15on-154`

However I would like to get it to work with `UCanAccess-5.0.1` but I just get errors and errors again when I try, if anyone knows how to do this I would appreciate the help.